# Get zip file from non-public folder (php)

Tags: javascript, php, zip

I have a zip file in a non-public folder of my web server.  I want to make the file not accessible by the public, so I was looking to use php readfile to read the zip file and create a File object from the zip file in javascript.  I am not sure if this is the best way to do something like this but would appreciate any suggestion.

How do I use the returned data to construct a File object?

Here is my php code (getZipFile.php):

```
<?php

$filename = "abc.zip";
    $filepath = "/path/to/zip/";

    // http headers for zip downloads
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
    ob_end_flush();
    $buffer = readfile($filepath . $filename);
    echo $buffer;
?>
```

And here is my javascript code

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'getZipFile.php',
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            var parts = [
              new Blob([data], {type: 'application/zip'}),
              new Uint16Array([33])
            ];

            var f = new File(parts, "myzip.zip");
        },
        type: 'GET'
    });
```

One thing I noticed is the size of th original Zip file is 2302 bytes, when I print data.length in the success function, the data length is 2287.  Should they be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Where does $buffer comes from ? Additionnaly you don't seem to be sending the file, you should add :

```
echo readfile($filepath . $filename);
```

You could also add some control to check if the file exists, but this is beyond your question's scope.

Comment: Hi, sorry that a line of code was missing from my original code. I have $buffer = readfile($filepath . $filename); before echo $buffer.  What it is giving me is an empty response text.

Comment: Could you try : if(realpath($filepath.$filename)){ readfile($filepath.$filename);}else{throw new Exception('error reading file');}

Comment: Thanks, my filepath is incorrect by accident and that explained why it gave an empty response string.  Should have done what you suggested and check if the file exists first before calling readfile.

Comment: I still have some problem with the javascript code reading the file.... The zip file didnt seem to be loading correctly after it was created as a File object..   Maybe there is something wrong with the parts variable?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of my depth concerning File object. I hope you will get an answer.

Comment: How do I use the returned data to construct a File object? It says the first argument to construct a File object must be an array of text.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you give me the link to the documentation you're using ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using XMLHttpRequest to handle the request and specified blob as my return data type.  This is my final code.

php code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$filename = "abc.zip";
$filepath = "/path/to/zip/";
$zip = $filepath . $filename;
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
ob_clean(); 
flush();
readfile($filepath . $filename);
exit;
```

javascript code:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "getZipFile.php", true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";
oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    var data = oReq.response;
    var f = new File([data], "myzip.zip", {
        lastModified: new Date(0),
        type: "application/zip"
    });
};
oReq.send();
```